# ChartJS doughnut data toggle on custom button click

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

is there a way to make some data in the doughnut ChartJS chart toggle? I have created some custom HTML/CSS and random data for the chart and I have tried to find a solution for the last 6 hours and there were only some tutorials on youtube which were not helping that much.

This is the HTML part:

```
<div class="mr-3 mt-4 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center legendBoxActionsContent">
                    <button id="category1" onclick="toggleData(0)"></button>
                    <span class="mt-2" id="doughnut_label_0"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="mr-3 mt-4 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center legendBoxActionsContent">
                    <button id="category1" onclick="toggleData(1)"></button>
                    <span class="mt-2" id="doughnut_label_1"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="mr-3 mt-4 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center legendBoxActionsContent">
                    <button id="category2" onclick="toggleData(2)"></button>
                    <span class="mt-2" id="doughnut_label_2"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="mr-3 mt-4 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center legendBoxActionsContent">
                    <button id="category3" onclick="toggleData(3)"></button>
                    <span class="mt-2" id="doughnut_label_3"></span>
                </div>
```

Here is only the relevant part of the chart script:

```
const myDashDoughnutChart = new Chart(dashDoughnutChart, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: ['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3', 'Cat4'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgb(143,219,226)',
                    'rgb(255,206,148)',
                    'rgb(158,239,181)',
                    'rgb(251,172,172)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgb(143,219,226)',
                    'rgb(255,206,148)',
                    'rgb(158,239,181)',
                    'rgb(251,172,172)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1,
            }]
        },
```

And this is the script I have found on the youtube but it does not work for me:

```
        function toggleData(value) {
        let showValue = myDashDoughnutChart.isDatasetVisible(value);
        
        if(showValue === true) {
            myDashDoughnutChart.hide(value)
        }

        if(showValue === false) {
            myDashDoughnutChart.show(value)
        }
```

Every button should hide one data from myDashDoughnutChart.data.datasets[0].data[] ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The toggle function could be written as follows:

```
function toggleData(button, category) {
  chart.toggleDataVisibility(category);
  chart.update();
  if (chart.getDataVisibility(category)) {
    button.classList.remove('hidden');
  } else {
    button.classList.add('hidden');
  }
}
```

> Further information about the Chart.js API can be found [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.0/developers/api.html).

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works:

```js
const chart = new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3', 'Cat4'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgb(143,219,226)',
        'rgb(255,206,148)',
        'rgb(158,239,181)',
        'rgb(251,172,172)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgb(143,219,226)',
        'rgb(255,206,148)',
        'rgb(158,239,181)',
        'rgb(251,172,172)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
});

function toggleData(button, category) {
  chart.toggleDataVisibility(category);
  chart.update();
  if (chart.getDataVisibility(category)) {
    button.classList.remove('hidden');
  } else {
    button.classList.add('hidden');
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;">
  <div style="display: flex; gap: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
    <button id="category0" onclick="toggleData(this, 0)">category0</button>
    <button id="category1" onclick="toggleData(this, 1)">category1</button>
    <button id="category2" onclick="toggleData(this, 2)">category2</button>
    <button id="category3" onclick="toggleData(this, 3)">category3</button>
  </div>
  <canvas id="chart" width="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: How could I get the original chart button color to fill the new button with such color?